# Spring Security - showing logout message

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring security java based configuration is (it's not spring mvc, just servlet webapp)

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsp")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

and login page is

```
<form name='loginForm' action="" method='POST'>

            <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                <p>You have been logged out.</p>
            </c:if>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
```

and there is other page with logout link, so logout action is `logout` (page 2)

```
<form action="logout" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
```

After I succesfully loged in and then pressed logout button (from page 2) it returned my to the login page but the login page did not show the logout message `<c:if test="${param.logout != null}">`. After that I try to log in again but it did not work (it is only login after logout) and showed me a logout message. Why it works that way and how to fix it to show logout message just after logout was pressed.

Comment: What make you believe that the param `param.logout` exists? - do you have any documentation or tutorial that describe/use it?

Comment: Found it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-form

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure the logout

```
http
        .logout()                                                                
            .logoutUrl("/logout")                                                 
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help.

Java configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/loginPage")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll();
}
```

And in logout page

```
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" 
                               method="POST" >                     
        <input type="submit" value="logout">                                       
   </form:form>
```